# Rails inspect a request header for "If-Modified-Since"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, caching

I am trying to build an API using Rails that will inspect the `request` header for `"If-Modified-Since"` and render only the objects that were modified past that date.  The problem is I am stuck trying to obtain the value from the request header in the controller.

```
# API
def index
   @products = Product.where{updated_at > request.headers["If-Modified-Since"]}
   render "v1/products/index"
end
```

What is the correct way for extracting values from the request header?

Comment: Can you specify what the code above does, and how it is different from what you expected it to do?

Comment: Ah, well request.headers["If-Modified-Since"] isn't actually returning anything for some reason.  I am wondering if that is the correct way to read the header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: `If-Modified-Since` is for HTTP cache validation. Please **don't use it this way**. Use a parameter instead.

To answer your question: `request.headers[]` is the proper way of accessing request headers. For reference, `request` is an [ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) object.

The problem here is how you're trying to express the constraint. You're passing a block into `ActiveRecord`'s `#where` method, and the block doesn't make any sense (`Symbol#>(String)`?). You can express this as a SQL fragment, like:

```
Product.where("updated_at > ?", params[:last_update])
```

Alternately, you could drop in [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel), and write:

```
Product.where{ updated_at > params[:last_update] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Will move to using a parameter instead of the HTTP header.

Comment: I don't see the point. I think the header should work for exactly that purpose. Can you give more arguments why this should only be used for caching?

Comment: Besides the fact that `If-Modified-Since` is [explicitly defined by HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25), and the fact that it's only used to make conditional requests, and the fact that HTTP tools (including browsers and CDNs and proxies) will use it in this fashion? No, I guess not.

Comment: But this is an API, for consumption by dedicated clients, not browsers or CDNs. If the usage is agreed between the clients and the API server, what's the problem? By the way, your heavy sarcasm is unconstructive and unwarranted when you were being asked a fair question.

Answer (score 3):

According to the W3 specifications, your method of using If-Modified-Since is completely valid. [[1]](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) The other responders here are incorrect in saying that it is non-standard or will corrupt your cache. It's not very RESTful and is not recommended to include state information within your data (such as GET parameters).

To answer you question, you can use `stale?` to generate either a 304 (if it hasn't been modified) or generate the actual content. Here's an example:

```
def index
  if_modified_since = request.headers['If-Modified-Since'] || DateTime.new
  @items = Item.where("updated_at > ?", if_modified_since).order(updated_at: :desc)
  if stale?(@items.first)
    render json: @items
  end
end
```

Note that this assumes @items always contains an item. You can tailor it to your needs if it doesn't always return something.

Answer (score 1):

`request.if_modified_since` or `request.headers["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]`

Be aware that this is a non-standard use of the header. It generally refers to whether *any* content of the page has changed since the time specified in If-Modified-Since, not that the page should only include the content which has changed.

You might also be interested in the [`stale?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83d29a283ceb13ff431da535e8cc35db6828016c/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/conditional_get.rb#L103) method.